# Stripe Payment issue to multiple account

Tags: java, stripe-payments

Requirement: In my project I have to process sum of multiple payment. For ex: $1+$2=$3. So I have to process the payment of $3 in stripe and want to transfer the $1 and $2 in different account of Connect after successfull payment. So How can I achieve this. here is my implementation but this is giving me an error "You have insufficient funds in your Stripe account." and getting an error at line "Transfer transfer = Transfer.create(transferParams);"

```
@PostMapping("/multiple-payment")
public Object multiplePaymentIntent(@RequestBody MultiplePaymentRequest multiple) throws StripeException {
  Stripe.apiKey = stripeApiKey;
  PaymentIntentCreateParams params =
    PaymentIntentCreateParams.builder()
      .addPaymentMethodType("card")
      .setAmount(multiple.getTotalAmount()*1L)
      .setCurrency("usd")
      .setReceiptEmail("example@gmail.com")
      .setTransferGroup("{ORDER10}")
      .build();
  PaymentIntent paymentIntent = PaymentIntent.create(params);
  for(int i=0;i<multiple.getAccount().size();i++){
    TransferCreateParams transferParams =
      TransferCreateParams.builder()
        .setAmount(multiple.getAmount().get(i)*1L)
        .setCurrency("usd")
        .setDestination(multiple.getAccount().get(i))
        .setTransferGroup("{ORDER10}")
        .build();

    Transfer transfer = Transfer.create(transferParams);

  }
  return paymentIntent.toJson();
}
```

and RequestBody is

```
public class MultiplePaymentRequest {
  Integer totalAmount;
  List<String> account;
  List<Integer> amount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't transfer immediately because the funds haven't settled yet to be available in your Stripe platform balance, that takes a few days.

You'd generally use `source_transaction` here so you can call the Transfer API and link it to the payment. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#transfer-availability

See also this: [Why I am getting 'insufficient funds' when trying Stripe Transfers even though I added TEST mode funds in my Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686949/why-i-am-getting-insufficient-funds-when-trying-stripe-transfers-even-though-i/55687932#55687932)