# Stripe balance 0

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a stripe account from which I am trying to transfer money to a connected account but the transaction fails with error message :
I want to increase my stripe account balance .
Error message :

```
StripeInvalidRequestError: You have insufficient funds in your Stripe account. One likely reason you have insufficient funds is that your funds are automatically being paid out; try enabling manual payouts by going to https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/payouts.
    at StripeError.generate (file:///C:/Users/gauth/OneDrive/Desktop/AAK/Blockchain-Dev/node_modules/stripe/esm/Error.js:7:20)
    at res.toJSON.then.StripeAPIError.message (file:///C:/Users/gauth/OneDrive/Desktop/AAK/Blockchain-Dev/node_modules/stripe/esm/RequestSender.js:102:43)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
  raw: {
    code: 'balance_insufficient',
    doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/balance-insufficient',
    message: 'You have insufficient funds in your Stripe account. One likely reason you have insufficient funds is that your funds are automatically being paid out; try enabling manual payouts by going to https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/payouts.',
    request_log_url: 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_pREFCj6uj3D7LY?t=1683200590',
    type: 'invalid_request_error',
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Thu, 04 May 2023 11:43:10 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '520',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
      'access-control-max-age': '300',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
      'idempotency-key': 'c6f32e35-9fc1-4ce6-bba8-3ec82c2f2ae9',        
      'original-request': 'req_pREFCj6uj3D7LY',
      'request-id': 'req_pREFCj6uj3D7LY',
      'stripe-should-retry': 'false',
      'stripe-version': '2020-08-27',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
    },
    statusCode: 400,
    requestId: 'req_pREFCj6uj3D7LY'
  },
  rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
  code: 'balance_insufficient',
  doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/balance-insufficient',  
  param: undefined,
  detail: undefined,
  headers: {
    server: 'nginx',
    date: 'Thu, 04 May 2023 11:43:10 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '520',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
    'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE', 
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
    'access-control-max-age': '300',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
    'idempotency-key': 'c6f32e35-9fc1-4ce6-bba8-3ec82c2f2ae9',
    'original-request': 'req_pREFCj6uj3D7LY',
    'request-id': 'req_pREFCj6uj3D7LY',
    'stripe-should-retry': 'false',
    'stripe-version': '2020-08-27',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
  },
  requestId: 'req_pREFCj6uj3D7LY',
  statusCode: 400,
  charge: undefined,
  decline_code: undefined,
  payment_intent: undefined,
  payment_method: undefined,
  payment_method_type: undefined,
  setup_intent: undefined,
  source: undefined
}
```

I tried to get my account balance and I got :

```
{
  object: 'balance',
  available: [ { amount: 0, currency: 'usd', source_types: [Object] } ],
  connect_reserved: [ { amount: 0, currency: 'usd' } ],
  livemode: false,
  pending: [ { amount: 276, currency: 'usd', source_types: [Object] } ] 
}
```

I want to know how to increase my account balance. I am trying this in test mode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I am getting 'insufficient funds' when trying Stripe Transfers even though I added TEST mode funds in my Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686949/why-i-am-getting-insufficient-funds-when-trying-stripe-transfers-even-though-i)

Comment: Hi Karllekko, Thank you it worked I used the card ending with 0077 and it worked .